# How to prevent a new object of robots from going to the same location as previous robots?

Tags: javascript, arrays

## **Things you need to know about my Program**

I have created a program in JavaScript that executes Robot instruction that you give. per Robot Object.

The robot is inside a rectangle shaped area. It moves with (x,y) points. Such that **(0 <= x <= 50)** and **(0 <= y <= 50)**

1. The instructions are in Strings of continuous of three repeated letters - There are Three letter that represent the movement of the robot
2. The program runs each letter and moves the robot according to the letter.
3. If the program finds out the the robot is out of the surface. Then the robot is lost and the coordinates of that particular robot is kept in array of lists called **Lost_Robot**

## My Question:

I don't know how to prevent a new robot from going to the same coordinates that a previous robot got lost (because of out of Rectangle surface).

How can I achieve from preventing another new robot (when I say new Robot, I mean new Robot Object) from jumping to the same location that a previous robot went and got lost.

I have an array of (x,y) of robots that got lost. But how can I use this array from letting a new robot going to this point?

I tried to use for loop that runs the array to see the coordinates, but doesn't do anything.

## Also

While your working on my problem, can you also give me few hints on how can I simplify my code yet doing the same functionality, but more efficiently.

=

```js
var orientation = ["N", "E", "S", "W"];
var instruction = ["L", "R", "F"];
var lost_Robot_Scent = [];

// function created for assigning coordinates and an orientation
function Robot_Coordinatation(x, y, orientation) {
  // coordinate (x,y) must be located at (0,0) at the initial state of the program
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  // orientation assigned
  this.orientation = orientation;
  // this is printed for the purpose of tidiness
  document.write("============================" + "<br />");
  // | ( x,y) | e.g(S)
  document.write("| ( " + x + ", " + y + " ) | " + orientation + "<br />");


  // We have a nested function here that will determine the movement/instruction of the robot
  this.Robot_Instruction = function(instruct_The_Robot) {
    // We are making sure here that the length of the instruction is less than 100
    if (instruct_The_Robot.length <= 100) {
      // if...statement - if x & y is bigger than or equal to 0 and smaller than or equal to 50 -> If its true then go inside the if statment.
      // Essentiallly, what this statement is actually doing is that its creating the rectangular grid.
      if ((x <= 50 && x >= 0) && (y <= 50 && y >= 0)) {
        // itterate the array of the instruct_The_Robot
        for (var i = 0; i < instruct_The_Robot.length; i++) {
          // if any value of instruct_The_Robot is strictly equal to "L", then go inside this if statement. refer to line: 10
          if (instruct_The_Robot[i] === instruction[0]) {
            // variable Left declared and instantiated with -90°
            var Left = -90 + "&#176";
            // variable result instantiated with value (x,y) & orientation
            var result = " | ( " + x + ", " + y + " ) " + " | " + orientation + " " + Left + "<br />";
            // however, if the if...statment at line: 33 is not true, then follow this : if the value of instruct_The_Robot is equal to "R"...
          } else if (instruct_The_Robot[i] === instruction[1]) {
            // variable Right instantiated with 90°
            var Right = 90 + "&#176";
            // variable result instantiated
            var result = " | ( " + x + ", " + y + " ) " + " | " + orientation + " " + Right + "<br />";
            // however, if the if...statment at line: 33 & elseif at line: 39 is not true, then if instruct_The_Robot is equal to "F"...
          } else if (instruct_The_Robot[i] === instruction[2]) {
            // variable y_Plus_One is instantiated with the current value of y and moves y one point forward
            var y_Plus_One = y += 1;
            // if the negation of x & y_Plus_One is smaller than 50 and bigger the 0, then...
            if (!((x <= 50 && x >= 0) && (y_Plus_One <= 50 && y_Plus_One >= 0))) {
              // then print " lost! "
              document.write("LOST!" + "<br />");
              // & keep the record of the x and y_Plus_One value to the lost_Robot_Scent array
              lost_Robot_Scent.push([x, y]);
              // and return false - this stops printing "Lost!" more than one times
              return false;
              // Otherwise, if the above doesn't satisfy, then...
            } else {
              // variable result instantiated with the updated coordinates (y_Plus_One)
              var result = " | ( " + x + ", " + y_Plus_One + " ) " + " | " + orientation + " " + "<br />";
            }
          }
        }
        //print the result
        document.write(result);
        // if none of the if...statement above satisfy, then...
      } else {
        // variale lost instantiated with "Lost!" message
        var lost = "LOST!" + "<br />";
        // push the robot to the lost_Robot_Scent
        lost_Robot_Scent.push("| ( " + x + ", " + y + " ) " + "<br />");
      }
    } else {
      alert("There is alot of of instructions given. Please make sure that the instruction is less than 100 instructions");
    }
  }
}

// new Robot object initialised
var one = new Robot_Coordinatation(50, 50, orientation[1]);
one.Robot_Instruction("LRLRLRLRLRLLRRLRLRLLRLLRRLL");

var two = new Robot_Coordinatation(20, 30, orientation[3]);
two.Robot_Instruction("FFFLLFLRLFLRFLRLLLFRL");

var two = new Robot_Coordinatation(30, 7, orientation[3]);
two.Robot_Instruction("FFFFLRLFLRFLRL");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Maintaining `lost_Robot_Scent`

I can help you with keeping a collection of locations where your robots get lost (your `lost_Robot_Scent` array). I suggest using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead on an `Array`. Sets provide O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup. This probably isn't a big deal in this situation, but it's good to know about `Set` anyway.

The main problem you'll run into is that array equality is *pointer* equality: for example, `[1, 1] === [1, 1]` returns `false`. One workaround is using `toString()` on the arrays and storing *that* in the `Set`. For example:

```
var lost_Robot_Scent = new Set();
lost_Robot_Scent.add( [1, 1].toString() );

lost_Robot_Scent.has( [1, 1].toString() ); // -> true
lost_Robot_Scent.has( [2, 2].toString() ); // -> false
```

I don't know if this is the cleanest solution, but it works. If you want to use an `Array` instead of a `Set`, just use `push` instead of `add` and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (or `indexOf`) instead of `has`, e.g.

```
var lost_Robot_Scent = [];
lost_Robot_Scent.push( [1, 1].toString() );

lost_Robot_Scent.includes( [1, 1].toString() ); // -> true
lost_Robot_Scent.includes( [2, 2].toString() ); // -> false
```

If you are worried about performance, you can test these two methods against each other in specific contexts.

### Improve The Code

One thing you can do to simplify your code is to lessen the nested `if` statements. For example, the first `if` in your `Robot_Instruction` function could be

```
if (instruct_The_Robot.length > 100) {
    alert("Too many instructions! Please limit to 100."
    return;
}

// continue...
```

Perhaps this is a bit off-topic, but you should only use comments for things are aren't obvious. For example, `variable Left declared and instantiated with -90°` is unnecessary.

One last thing: you can simplify the "instructions" loop using a `switch` statement instead of `if/else` blocks. Or, if you want to make is super-readable, you can use a JavaScript object like so:

```
var move = {
    L: function() {
        // turn left
    },
    R: function() {
        // turn right
    },
    F: function() {
        // move forward
    },
};

// then, in the "instructions" loop, you can just do
for (var i = 0; i < instruct_The_Robot.length; i++) {
    move[ instruct_The_Robot[i] ]();
}
```

That's a pretty neat trick.

Comment: I see what you are doing there. I probably change Arrays to set because this is one of the feature I actually need. Thanks!

Can this program be more simplified? Is this efficient way of implementing JavaScript rules?

Comment: I updated my answer with a few suggestions. I hope it helps!

Comment: Wow Nicolas! Your awesome. You made is so super readable. Thanks. I will surely implement your ideas into this. I hope to receive more help from you in the future.

Good Day!

Comment: You're welcome! (By the way, an upvote on the answer would be much appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

**How to prevent a new robots from getting lost in the same places as old robots**

Assuming you've fixed your bugs, and robots are moving. When you determine that a robot is moving forward, you have to determine if the new coordinates are already in the `lost_Robot_Scent` array. You can do this using something like the following:

```
var robotLostAtSameLocation = false;

for (var i = 0; i < lost_Robot_Scent.length; i++) {
  var lostRobotLocation = lost_Robot_Scent[i];

  if(lostRobotLocation[0] === x && lostRobotLocation[1] === y) {
    robotLostAtSameLocation = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (robotLostAtSameLocation) {
  // whatever you want to do in this case
}
else {
  // whatever you want to do in this case
}
```

**Simple optimization**

Note that you can get rid of this loop if you change the `lost_Robot_Scent` array from containing `[x,y]` to containing something like `'x:y'`. So rather than an array that contains other arrays looking like this: `[[39,51], [51,15], [-1,11]]`, it will be an array containing strings looking like: `['39:51', '51:15', '-1:11']`. What this buys you is that you can then just say `var robotLostAtSameLocation = lost_Robot_Scent.indexOf(x + ':" + y) > -1;`

**Recommendation**

- Change `var instruction = ["L", "R", "F"];` into something more like `var INSTRUCTIONS = {LEFT: 'L', RIGHT: 'R', FORWARD: 'F'};`. This turns lines like `instruct_The_Robot[i] === instruction[0]` into `instruct_The_Robot[i] === INSTRUCTIONS.LEFT`, improving readability.

**Bugs**

- You are never updating x, y, or orientation. Your robots are never moving. You are only outputting a string.
- You are only checking if the y-coordinate is out of bounds. You are forgetting to check if the x-coordinate is out of bounds.
- You are pushing `[x,y]` into the `lost_Robot_Scent` array on one line, then pushing `"| ( " + x + ", " + y + " ) " + "<br />"` into the same array on another line. Don't do that. It's hard to reason about a program when it is not consistent.
- *There may be other issues - I can't take the time to fully digest it at the moment*.

Comment: Hi Seth! A very good feedback provided. Really appreciate it. I will surely implement what you have considered. Can this program be simplified even more? Is this more efficient way of doing it?